# JUnit Tests with classes that rely on other classes

Tags: java, class, junit

Hi i have this class Item

```
public class Item implements Cloneable {

    private String name;
    private int reorderAmount;


    public Item(String name, int reorderAmount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.reorderAmount = reorderAmount;

     }


   /**
     * @return The Amount of a reorder.
     */
    public int getReorderAmount() {
        return reorderAmount;
    }
}
```

My other class is Stock

```
public class Stock extends HashMap {

    private HashMap<String, Item> stock;

    /**
     * Constructor. Creates a stock. 
     */
    public Stock() {
        stock = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the total Quantity of Items for the next Order.
     * @return Number of total reorder quantity.
     */
    public int getTotalReorderAmount() {
        int reorderQuantity = 0;
        for (Item item : (Collection<Item>) this.values()) {
            reorderQuantity += item.getReorderAmount();
        }
        return reorderQuantity;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble running my JUnit test as my understanding on how one class effects another is lacking.

```
public class StockTests  {

            Stock stock; 
            Item item; 


            // Clear the item and stock object before every test 
            @Before
            public void setUp() {
                String name = "bread";
                Integer reorderAmount = 100; 
                item = new Item(name, reorderAmount);

                stock = null;
            }

            /*
             * Test 1: Test the total number of items needed.
             */
            @Test
            public void testReorderAmount() {
                stock = new Stock();
                assertEquals(100, stock.getTotalReorderAmount());
            }

}
```

What I have currently done is created an Item 'bread' inside the @before of my Junit testing class with 100 as the reorder amount. I am testing to see if my method getTotalReorderAmount inside my Stock Class is returning 100 however my JUnit results tell me it is returning 0. This is where i believe that i am creating the Item incorrectly within the JUnit Class.

Comment: `stock` in the @Test is a new instance so it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: There's no method in your `Stock` class that adds any items, so you can't ever add any items to it (and thus your test returns 0 as expected.) Also, why does `Stock` extend `HashMap`? (Your setup() method does create an item, but it doesn't get added to anything.)

Answer (score 0):

In your `testReorderAmount` method, you have to set `item` you created.

**Firstly** modify your `Stock` class to have a method which adds item in `private HashMap<String, Item> stock`.
i.e. you class `Stock` could look like:

```
public class Stock {

  .............

    private HashMap<String, Item> stock;

    public void addItemToStock(String itemName, Item item){
       stock.put(itemName, item);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Creates a stock. 
     */
    public Stock() {
        stock = new HashMap<>();
    }
 .........

}
```

**Secondly**, set the `item` inside the `stock` map in your junit test.

Your **test method** will look like :

```
 /*
 * Test 1: Test the total number of items needed.
 */
@Test
public void testReorderAmount() {
    stock = new Stock();
    stock.addItem("bread", this.item);
    assertEquals(100, stock.getTotalReorderAmount());
}
```

Comment: In this solution you leak a *mutable* map outside the stock class *bad idea*.

Comment: I downvoted it because of the exposure of the map, as it violated good design. Removed the downvote, now answer is practically the same as mine. Except that you pass the `name` of the item to the method, which introduces a risk as you can pass another name then the item has, and it 'leaks' a bit of the internal datastructure being a map.

Comment: Why would you pass the name `addItemToStock(String itemName, Item item)` when it can be got from the passed item?

Comment: how can we deduce that `stock`'s `name` is item name? It can be some other name like inventory name.

Answer (score 0):

You create an item, but never add it to the `Stock`.

A simplistic implementation:

```
 public class Stock {
     ....

     public void add(Item item) {
         stock.put(item.getName(), item);
     }
 }
```

Your test could be:

```
        /*
         * Test 1: Test the total number of items needed.
         */
        @Test
        public void testReorderAmount() {
            Stock stock = new Stock();
            stock.add(new Item("bread", 100));
            assertEquals(100, stock.getTotalReorderAmount());
        }
```

No need to use `setUp` in this case.

By the way, the most basic testcase (which is advisable to start with) is the empty stock:

```
@Test
public void emptyStock() {
   Stock stock = new Stock(); 
   assertEquals(0, stock.getTotalReorderAmount()); 
}
```